# Eloquent giving error but query executes fine in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I was trying to use groupBy for grouping all views by uni_id and their date of creation so I can generate reports. But I see Laravel Eloquent is generating error. However when I executed the same query in phpmyadmin, it shows me data. How does Eloquent process its queries?

I am using Laravel 5.2

This is the query I am trying to run through Eloquent:

```
    $data = UniversityView::
    groupBy('created_at', 'uni_id')
    ->select('uni_id', DB::raw('count(*) as views'), 'name', 'created_at')
    ->get();
```

**The question is not how to fix it. I fixed it already by putting 'name' in groupBy. But the question is why query is executing differently through Eloquent?**

Check images below for help. Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's caused by [MySQL's strict mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html), it is specified in your connection parameters array at `config/database.php` that's why when you execute it directly at `phpMyAdmin` it is working, because `phpMyAdmin` uses different connection parameters.

You can disable it partially, to allow this kind of groupsBy, by modifying your `config/database.php` connection array. Do it in this way:

Add `modes` array to only disable this rule:

```
 'strict' => true,
 'modes' => ['STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
            'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
            'NO_ZERO_DATE',
            'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
            'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
            'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'],
```

Or if you know what you are doing you can do directly (I won't do it):

```
'strict' => false,
```